# Variable used in more functions

Tags: node.js

How can I create a variable that is used in two separate functions, or more, without having to declare it globally? I am using NodeJS for the record.

Comment: Hi Dark. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating what you have attempted thus far. Stack Overflow is not a code writing or homework service. Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### If all functions are in one file

Just declare it outside of the scope of the functions and it will be available inside:

```
const myVar = 'hello';

function firstFunc() {
  console.log(myVar);
}

function secondFunc() {
  console.log(myVar);
}

/* and so on ... */
```

#### If these functions exist across multiple files

Create a module for accessing this variable and require it in the files that you need it. A caveat here is that you won't be able to change the variable in one file and have that change reflected in another. The only way I know how to do that is using global variables.

./myModule.js

```
module.exports = 'hello';
```

./firstFile.js

```
const myVar = require('./myModule');

function firstFunc() {
  console.log(myVar);
}
```

./secondFile.js

```
const myVar = require('./myModule');

function secondFunc() {
  console.log(myVar);
}
```

Hopefully this answers your question. Cheers

Comment: Thanks!! this makes total sense!